# Setting up wifi network with OpenWrt

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, openwrt

**I have** router MR3020 with OpenWrt.

**I need** wifi network with access to an admin panel of the router and the Internet from the another network.

I have another network "BigWifi" (not mine), and I connect my router to it. BigWifi give IP to clients by itself, so I just connect my router by LAN (RJ-45). If router is set as bridge (wan and lan are bridged) the internet is working fine, but no access to admin panel, *my IP is in subnet of BigWifi network*. If I delete this bridge (wan and lan not bridged) -- I can access to panel, *my IP is in subnet of my WiFi network*, but can't to the Internet.
How should I configure my router to access both the internet and the admin panel of my router?

I have read about routing, but it's not helped me.

My files:

**/etc/config/network:**

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'

config interface 'wifi'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.2.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
```

**/etc/config/wireless:**

```
config wifi-device  radio0
    option type     mac80211
    option channel  11
    option macaddr  c4:6e:1f:c7:b6:62
    option hwmode   11ng
    option htmode   HT20
    list ht_capab   SHORT-GI-20
    list ht_capab   SHORT-GI-40
    list ht_capab   RX-STBC1
    list ht_capab   DSSS_CCK-40
    # REMOVE THIS LINE TO ENABLE WIFI:
    option disabled 0

config wifi-iface
    option device   radio0
    option network  wifi
    option mode     ap
    option ssid     OpenWrt
    option encryption none
```

**/etc/config/firewall:**

```
config defaults
    option syn_flood '1'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'

config zone
    option name 'wan'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option masq '1'
    option mtu_fix '1'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'
    option network ' '

config rule
    option name 'Allow-DHCP-Renew'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dest_port '68'
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option family 'ipv4'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-Ping'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    option icmp_type 'echo-request'
    option family 'ipv4'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-DHCPv6'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option src_ip 'fe80::/10'
    option src_port '547'
    option dest_ip 'fe80::/10'
    option dest_port '546'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Input'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    list icmp_type 'echo-request'
    list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
    list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
    list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
    list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
    list icmp_type 'bad-header'
    list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
    list icmp_type 'router-solicitation'
    list icmp_type 'neighbour-solicitation'
    list icmp_type 'router-advertisement'
    list icmp_type 'neighbour-advertisement'
    option limit '1000/sec'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Forward'
    option src 'wan'
    option dest '*'
    option proto 'icmp'
    list icmp_type 'echo-request'
    list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
    list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
    list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
    list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
    list icmp_type 'bad-header'
    list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
    option limit '1000/sec'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config include
    option path '/etc/firewall.user'

config zone
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'
    option network ' '
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option name 'lan'
    option masq '1'
    option mtu_fix '1'

config forwarding
    option dest 'wan'
    option src 'lan'
```

**/etc/config/dhcp:**

```
config dnsmasq
    option domainneeded 1
    option boguspriv    1
    option filterwin2k  0  # enable for dial on demand
    option localise_queries 1
    option rebind_protection 1  # disable if upstream must serve RFC1918 addresses
    option rebind_localhost 1  # enable for RBL checking and similar services
    #list rebind_domain example.lan  # whitelist RFC1918 responses for domains
    option local    '/lan/'
    option domain   'lan'
    option expandhosts  1
    option nonegcache   0
    option authoritative    1
    option readethers   1
    option leasefile    '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
    option resolvfile   '/tmp/resolv.conf.auto'
    #list server        '/mycompany.local/1.2.3.4'
    #option nonwildcard 1
    #list interface     br-lan
    #list notinterface  lo
    #list bogusnxdomain     '64.94.110.11'

config dhcp lan
    option interface    lan
    option start    100
    option limit    150
    option leasetime    12h

config dhcp wan
    option interface    wan
    option ignore   1

config dhcp wifi
    option interface    wifi
    option start        100
    option limit        150 
    option leasetime    12h
```